# How can I execute multiple groups of parallel requests in parallel in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am testing an application which invokes multiple groups of parallel requests as seen in the screenshot below. This screenshot is taken from the browser network tab.

[image: WaterFall]

The request sequence is as follows:

1. Requests R1, R2 and R3 (Group-1) are invoked in parallel.
2. After request R1 is complete, requests R4, R5 and R6 (Group-2) are invoked in parallel. *R4, R5 and R6 use values from R1's response*.
3. After request R2 is complete, requests R7, R8, R9 and R10 (Group-3) are invoked in parallel. *R7, R8, R9 and R10 use values from R2's response*.

How can I achieve this in JMeter?

***NOTE**: The best I could come up with was this test plan using the Parallel Controller.*

[image: TestPlan]

*But I think this is not exactly right as the two thread groups execute independently of each other. The first thread group will not wait for the second thread group to complete before starting a new loop.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put **everything** as a child of a single Parallel Controller.

It's `Limit max thread number` option defaulting to `6` matches real browser setting when it comes to thread pool fetching [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) and executing [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) calls

[image]

Given well behaved JMeter test must represent a real user using a real browser with 100% accuracy I would expect that your test plan should be configured something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wouldn't your test plan just execute all requests in parallel? I have described the sequence of requests in my question and that is how the browser executes the requests as you can see from the first screenshot, which is from the actual browser network tab. And I should have included it initially, but I have updated the question to include the fact that requests in Group-2 require values from R1 response and requests in Group-3 require values from R2 response. So simply invoking all requests in parallel will not work and will not represent real browser behavior.